# How to use cocoa bindings with keys in your document subclass?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa-bindings

Here is the definition of my `freqstart` variable in my Swift app:

[image]

This is inside my `NSDocument` subclass, `NECDocument`. My `NECDocumentVC` subclasses `NSViewController` and has a link to `NECDocument`, so I can access those vars from the VC:

[image]

Note that both objects are part of the NS* class hierarchy, so everything should work fine with KVO.

I am using it this way:

[image]

The problem is that the key path is invalid, as you can see from the grey *!* in the field. For fun, I placed the same variable in my VC, and presto, the value came up fine. I've tried a bunch of different syntax's in the key path, but nothing I've tried works. Is there something about that `document` that needs to be different?

I started over - I added an `NSObjectController` to the storyboard, set its class to NECDocument and it's binding to NECDocumentVC->self.document. Then I bound the text field to point to the OC, and now it auto-completed "freqstart" with no *!*. The only problem is that now it says "No selection", and it's not clear how I would change the selection, which is read only.

I don't want to put all my variables in my VC, that's simply not where they belong. So can someone suggest a way to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

I added a Referencing Outlet to my DocumentVC, and then added `SettingsController?.addObject(document!)` to the `viewDidAppear`. Now running the app results in:

2016-03-03 14:28:05.880 SwiftNEC[73373:6282035] Cannot update for observer  for the key path "document.usegreens" from , most likely because the value for the key "document" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the SwiftNEC.NECDocumentVC class.

Ok, so is it possible to use a calculated property like my definition of document with KVO?

Comment: The tooltip of the ! says "Xcode cannot resolve the entered keypath". The key path can still be valid. The ! is red if there is a real problem.

Comment: Concur with Wileke, gray ! does not indicate failure, it just indicates that Interface Builder failed to resolve.  Our project has these in all of our bindings we setup through interface builder, and everything works.  The only thing I question is the need for `self` in the keypath, but offhand I'm not sure what's wrong with your binding

Comment: Ok, let me keep playing. Do you guys link from one object to the next like this?

Comment: Yes, I ignore the !.

Comment: `self` in the keypath can be omitted.

Comment: Still nothing, both with and without the self. Very annoying, it seems to have something to do with the path to the document object, but I can't imagine what.

Comment: You are changing the document property of the vc in a non-KVO way. Try setting `content` of the object controller instead of `addObject` and don't bind the content object of the object controller.

Comment: BINGO! You nailed it @Willeke. I added `SettingsController?.content = document!` in my `viewDidAppear` and the values came through immediately. It doesn't answer why the first method doesn't work, but this solves the problem. If you make that an answer I'll up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the document property of the vc in a non-KVO way.
Instead of binding the content of the object controller, do `SettingsController?.content = document!` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: It is still not clear *exactly* what the problem is, but it has something to do with the document method. dynamic is supposed to fix that, but doesn't. In any event, using this method solved the problem.